# XSLT 2.0: Creating child elements from an element's text value via known semantic hierarchy

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

A bit stuck on this one.  Data is provided in the following format (non-important content snipped):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Content Type="Statutes">
  <Indexes>
    <!--SNIP-->
    <Index Level="3" HasChildren="0">
      <!--SNIP-->
      <Content>&lt;p&gt; (1)(a)The statutes ... &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (b)To ensure public ..: &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; 
            (I)Shall authorize ...; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (II)May authorize and ...: &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (A)Compact disks; 
            &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (B)On-line public ...; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (C)Electronic applications for ..; 
            &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (D)Electronic books or ... &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (E)Other electronic products or formats; 
            &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (III)May, pursuant ... &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (IV)Recognizes that ... &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; 
            (2)(a)Any person, ...: &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (I)A statement specifying ...; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (II)A statement 
            specifying ...; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (3)A statement 
            specifying ...; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (4)A statement 
            specifying ...; &lt;/p&gt;</Content>
    </Index>
    <!--SNIP-->
  </Indexes>
</Content>
```

Need to take the text value of element **Content** which contains a semantic hierarchy:

```
(1)
 +-(a)
    +-(I)
       +-(A)
```

...and place via XSLT 2.0 transformation as a parent-child element relationship as the final output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <law>
       <!--SNIP-->
       <content>
          <section prefix="(1)">
            <section prefix="(a)">The statutes ...
            <section prefix="(b)">To ensure public ..:
              <section prefix="(I)">Shall authorize ...;</section>
              <section prefix="(II)">May authorize and ...:
                <section prefix="(A)">Compact disks;</section>
                <section prefix="(B)">On-line public ...;</section>
                <section prefix="(C)">Electronic applications for ..;</section>
                <section prefix="(D)">Electronic books or ...</section>
                <section prefix="(E)">Other electronic products or formats;</section>
              </section>
              <section prefix="(III)">May, pursuant ...</section>
              <section prefix="(IV)">Recognizes that ...</section>        
            </section>      
          </section>
          <section prefix="(2)">
            <section prefix="(a)">Any person, ...:
              <section prefix="(I)">A statement specifying ...;</section>
              <section prefix="(II)">A statement specifying ...;</section>
            </section>      
          </section>
          <section prefix="(3)">Level 1 node with no children</section>
       </content>
    </law>
```

I was able to tokenize the ending html-encoded P tags from Content's text value, but no clue how to get dynamically created elements to create child elements on conditionals.

My XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Content">
        <!-- Work from the lowest index level with no children up -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Index[@HasChildren=0]"/>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="Index[@HasChildren=0]">
        <law>
            <structure>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Content"/>
            </structure>
        </law>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template for Content element from originial -->
    <xsl:template match="Content">
        <content>
            <!-- Loop through HTML encoded P tag endings -->
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'&lt;/p&gt;')">

                <!-- Set Token to a variable and remove P opening tags -->
                <xsl:variable name="sectionText">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(current(),'&lt;p&gt;',''))"/>  
                </xsl:variable>    

                <!-- Output -->
                <xsl:if test="string-length($sectionText)!=0">
                    <section>
                        <!-- Set the section element's prefix attribute (if exists) -->
                        <xsl:analyze-string select="$sectionText" regex="^(\(([\w]+)\)){{1,3}}">
                            <xsl:matching-substring >
                                <xsl:attribute name="prefix" select="." />
                            </xsl:matching-substring>
                        </xsl:analyze-string>

                        <!-- Set the section element's value -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="$sectionText"/>
                    </section>
                </xsl:if>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </content>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...which gets me out this far - doesn't have the semantic hierarchy within the **section** elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<law>
   <structure>
      <content>
         <section prefix="(1)(a)">(1)(a)The statutes ...</section>
         <section prefix="(b)">(b)To ensure public ..:</section>
         <section prefix="(I)">(I)Shall authorize ...;</section>
         <section prefix="(II)">(II)May authorize and ...:</section>
         <section prefix="(A)">(A)Compact disks;</section>
         <section prefix="(B)">(B)On-line public ...;</section>
         <section prefix="(C)">(C)Electronic applications for ..;</section>
         <section prefix="(D)">(D)Electronic books or ...</section>
         <section prefix="(E)">(E)Other electronic products or formats;</section>
         <section prefix="(III)">(III)May, pursuant ...</section>
         <section prefix="(IV)">(IV)Recognizes that ...</section>
         <section prefix="(2)(a)">(2)(a)Any person, ...:</section>
         <section prefix="(I)">(I)A statement specifying ...;</section>
         <section prefix="(II)">(II)A statement specifying ...;</section>
         <section prefix="(3)">(3)Level 1 section with no children ...;</section>
      </content>
   </structure>
</law>
```

Since the **Section** elements are being created *dynamically* by the XSLT 2.0 stylesheet via tokenizing the end P tags, how do you build the **parent-child relationship** ***dynamically*** with the known semantic hierarchy via the **prefix** attribute?

Other programming language experiences point me in the direction of recursion based on the tokenization and logic on the prefix to its previous prefix for nesting - struggling to find any information on how to do this with my limited XSLT knowledge with v2.0 (used v1.0 almost 10+ years ago).  I know I could just parse with an external Python script and be done, *but trying to stick to a XSLT 2.0 stylesheet solution for maintainability.*

**Any help is appreciated to get me on the right track and/or solution.**

Comment: Take a look at this, it should get you the right track: http://www.saxonica.com/html/papers/ideadb-1.1/mhk-paper.html#d4e153, from the paragraph that starts "Any problem that involves adding hierarchic levels to the result tree, that were not present in the source tree, can be regarded as a grouping problem..."

Comment: What format exactly (HTML, XHTML, XML) is inside the `Content` element? Which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? There is better support to parse XML http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/PR-xpath-functions-30-20131022/#func-parse-xml or XML fragments http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/PR-xpath-functions-30-20131022/#func-parse-xml-fragment in XSLT 3.0 than in XSLT 2.0 and some releases already support those functions. If you have HTML in there then http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/extensions/functions/parse-html.html can help.

Comment: The Content element is URL encoded HTML without line endings - see top example.  The "..." was to shorten the text blocks between P tags for this question.

Comment: Regarding this: ""I know I could just parse with an external Python script and be done, *but trying to stick to a XSLT 2.0 stylesheet solution for maintainability.*""

Any solution to do this in XSLT is going to be very obtuse and complex. A short python/perl/whatever script could do this in a simpler, more readable way. **Why do you think XSLT the right tool for this job?**

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Because I can't be the first person that has to transform an html content string into an XML tree. :-)

Comment: Ignoring that you are taking escaped HTML (which isn't valid XML) and transforming it via XSLT. You are then trying to parse text in that HTML and trying to build a XML tree from *that*. This isn't as simple as `HTML -> XSLT -> XML`, this is another level entirely. Is it possible in XSLT 2.0+ probably; is it novel, certainly; is it the most maintainable solution, probably not.

Comment: @Stormtroopr If you're not used to the language, then arriving at an XSLT 2.0 solution may be tricky. But once you've got the solution you'll probably find that it is more concise and elegant than a solution using a low-level procedural language; it will therefore by definition be more maintainable, and it's also more likely to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with this a bit and came up with the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
 xmlns:d="data:,dpc" 
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs d mf">

    <xsl:include href="htmlparse.xml"/>

    <xsl:param name="patterns" as="element(pattern)*" xmlns="">
      <pattern value="^\s*(\([0-9]+\))" group="1" next="1"/>
      <pattern value="^\s*(\([0-9]+\))?\s*(\([a-z]\))" group="2" next="0"/>
      <pattern value="^\s*(\(*(I|II|III|IV|V|VI|VII|VIII|IX|X|XI|XII|XIII)\))" group="1" next="0"/>
      <pattern value="^\s*(\([A-Z]?\))" group="1" next="0"/>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(section)*">
      <xsl:param name="paragraphs" as="element(p)*"/>
      <xsl:param name="patterns" as="element(pattern)*"/>
      <xsl:variable name="pattern1" as="element(pattern)?" select="$patterns[1]"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$paragraphs" group-starting-with="p[matches(., $pattern1/@value)]">
        <xsl:variable name="prefix" as="xs:string?">
          <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$pattern1/@value}">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
              <xsl:sequence select="string(regex-group(xs:integer($pattern1/@group)))"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
          </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>
        <section prefix="{$prefix}">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="xs:boolean(xs:integer($pattern1/@next))">
              <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $patterns[position() gt 1])"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="pattern" as="element(pattern)" select="$pattern1" tunnel="yes"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
              <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., $patterns[position() gt 1])"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </section>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/Content">
        <!-- Work from the lowest index level with no children up -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Index[@HasChildren=0]"/>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="Index[@HasChildren=0]">
        <law>
            <structure>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Content"/>
            </structure>
        </law>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template for Content element from originial -->
    <xsl:template match="Content">

        <content>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(d:htmlparse(., '', true())/*, $patterns)"/>
        </content>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/text()[1]">
      <xsl:param name="pattern" as="element(pattern)" tunnel="yes"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $pattern/@value, '')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It makes use of http://web-xslt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl, an HTML tag soup parser written in XSLT 2.0, to parse the escaped HTML fragment markup into nodes which are then grouped using the function `mf:group` in the stylesheet. The grouping is driven by a sequence of regular expression patterns passed in as a parameter.

When applying the stylesheet with Saxon 9.5 to your input sample, I get the result

```
<law>
   <structure>
      <content>
         <section prefix="(1)">
            <section prefix="(a)">The statutes ... </section>
            <section prefix="(b)">To ensure public ..: <section prefix="(I)">Shall authorize ...; </section>
               <section prefix="(II)">May authorize and ...: <section prefix="(A)">Compact disks;
            </section>
                  <section prefix="(B)">On-line public ...; </section>
                  <section prefix="(C)">Electronic applications for ..;
            </section>
                  <section prefix="(D)">Electronic books or ... </section>
                  <section prefix="(E)">Other electronic products or formats;
            </section>
               </section>
               <section prefix="(III)">May, pursuant ... </section>
               <section prefix="(IV)">Recognizes that ... </section>
            </section>
         </section>
         <section prefix="(2)">
            <section prefix="(a)">Any person, ...: <section prefix="(I)">A statement specifying ...; </section>
               <section prefix="(II)">A statement
            specifying ...; </section>
            </section>
         </section>
      </content>
   </structure>
</law>
```

You would need to edit the parameter with the regular expression pattern for roman numbers to list more numbers if there can be more than 13 (XIII) sections as I have currently only listed the numbers including XIII.

Based on the comment and the edited input sample I have adapted the stylesheet a bit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
 xmlns:d="data:,dpc" 
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs d mf">

    <xsl:include href="htmlparse.xml"/>

    <xsl:param name="patterns" as="element(pattern)*" xmlns="">
      <pattern value="^\s*(\([0-9]+\))" group="1" next="1"/>
      <pattern value="^\s*(\([0-9]+\))?\s*(\([a-z]\))" group="2" next="0"/>
      <pattern value="^\s*(\(*(I|II|III|IV|V|VI|VII|VIII|IX|X|XI|XII|XIII)\))" group="1" next="0"/>
      <pattern value="^\s*(\([A-Z]?\))" group="1" next="0"/>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(section)*">
      <xsl:param name="paragraphs" as="element(p)*"/>
      <xsl:param name="patterns" as="element(pattern)*"/>
      <xsl:variable name="pattern1" as="element(pattern)?" select="$patterns[1]"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$paragraphs" group-starting-with="p[matches(., $pattern1/@value)]">
        <xsl:variable name="prefix" as="xs:string?">
          <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$pattern1/@value}">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
              <xsl:sequence select="string(regex-group(xs:integer($pattern1/@group)))"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
          </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:variable>
        <section prefix="{$prefix}">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="xs:boolean(xs:integer($pattern1/@next)) and matches(., $patterns[2]/@value)">
              <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $patterns[position() gt 1])"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="pattern" as="element(pattern)" select="$pattern1" tunnel="yes"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
              <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., $patterns[position() gt 1])"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </section>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/Content">
        <!-- Work from the lowest index level with no children up -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Index[@HasChildren=0]"/>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="Index[@HasChildren=0]">
        <law>
            <structure>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Content"/>
            </structure>
        </law>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template for Content element from originial -->
    <xsl:template match="Content">

        <content>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(d:htmlparse(., '', true())/*, $patterns)"/>
        </content>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/text()[1]">
      <xsl:param name="pattern" as="element(pattern)" tunnel="yes"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $pattern/@value, '')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now it transforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Content Type="Statutes">
  <Indexes>
    <!--SNIP-->
    <Index Level="3" HasChildren="0">
      <!--SNIP-->
      <Content>&lt;p&gt; (1)(a)The statutes ... &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (b)To ensure public ..: &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; 
            (I)Shall authorize ...; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (II)May authorize and ...: &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (A)Compact disks; 
            &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (B)On-line public ...; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (C)Electronic applications for ..; 
            &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (D)Electronic books or ... &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (E)Other electronic products or formats; 
            &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (III)May, pursuant ... &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (IV)Recognizes that ... &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; 
            (2)(a)Any person, ...: &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (I)A statement specifying ...; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (II)A statement 
            specifying ...; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (3)A statement 
            specifying ...; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; (4)A statement 
            specifying ...; &lt;/p&gt;</Content>
    </Index>
    <!--SNIP-->
  </Indexes>
</Content>
```

to

```
<law>
   <structure>
      <content>
         <section prefix="(1)">
            <section prefix="(a)">The statutes ... </section>
            <section prefix="(b)">To ensure public ..: <section prefix="(I)">Shall authorize ...; </section>
               <section prefix="(II)">May authorize and ...: <section prefix="(A)">Compact disks;
            </section>
                  <section prefix="(B)">On-line public ...; </section>
                  <section prefix="(C)">Electronic applications for ..;
            </section>
                  <section prefix="(D)">Electronic books or ... </section>
                  <section prefix="(E)">Other electronic products or formats;
            </section>
               </section>
               <section prefix="(III)">May, pursuant ... </section>
               <section prefix="(IV)">Recognizes that ... </section>
            </section>
         </section>
         <section prefix="(2)">
            <section prefix="(a)">Any person, ...: <section prefix="(I)">A statement specifying ...; </section>
               <section prefix="(II)">A statement
            specifying ...; </section>
            </section>
         </section>
         <section prefix="(3)">A statement
            specifying ...; </section>
         <section prefix="(4)">A statement
            specifying ...; </section>
      </content>
   </structure>
</law>
```

Comment: Discovered another condition I missed - updated the data provided to provide a level 1 element with no children. (section 3)  It seems to double up the section tagging with the above script.  Couldn't figure out how to detect that condition with mf:group.

Comment: @bandrzej, I have provided a second XSLT sample to address your edited input sample.

Comment: As I further went through my dataset, found additional conditions to cover that are beyond the scope of this question and/or cause parsing errors with the groupings.  Awarding points since it got me really close and wanted to simplify the initial question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884129/creating-parent-child-elements-from-semantic-hiearchy-in-element-values-in-xslt

Answer (score 2):

You've tackled one tricky phase of the problem to create an intermediate output with elements like this:

```
<section prefix="(1)(a)">text</section>
```

My next step would be to compute a level number, so it looks like this:

```
<section level="1" prefix="(1)(a)">text</section>
```

Computing the level number is simply a question of seeing which of several regular expressions the prefix matches: (1) gives you level 1, (b) gives you level 2, etc.

Once you've got level numbers you can use recursive positional grouping as described in this paper: http://www.saxonica.com/papers/ideadb-1.1/mhk-paper.xml

Comment: How would I get "process-level" template to re-iterate over the section tags in the XML result set?

Comment: Standard multi-phase transformation technique: capture the result tree in a variable, then process that tree. The technique is used extensively in the cited paper.

Comment: Wow - this XML pipelining is some powerful stuff!
http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslPipelines

This made more sense to me on how to pass the result tree to another template while the mhk-paper using call-template made sense for me to keep linear pipeline.  Did a quick test-case before venturing into extracting the level numbers out:

1) Captured the result tree into a variable

2) Pass said variable to a call-template with a param set as="element()*"

3) for-each loop the param - now have access to the elements and attributes to remold into a hiearchy