# Create hierarchy from list based on attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have been trying to put this list on a hierarchy based on the attribute count but I can't get right. At first was trying to do it all at one, the in phases but I keep running into the same problems when using preceding-sibling and following-sibling.

This is what I have

```
<body>
    <element count="2"/>
    <element count="2"/> 
    <element count="2"/> 
    <element count="2"/>
    <element count="4"/>
    <element count="4"/>
    <element count="6"/>
    <element count="4"/>
    <element count="2"/>
    <element count="4"/>
    <element count="2"/>
    <element count="4"/>
    <element count="6"/>
    <element count="6"/>
    <element count="4"/>
    <element count="2"/> 
 </body>
```

This is what I want

```
<body>
    <element count="2"/>
    <element count="2"/> 
    <element count="2"/> 
    <element count="2">
        <element count="4"/>
        <element count="4">
            <element count="6"/>
        </element>
        <element count="4"/>
    </element>
    <element count="2">
        <element count="4"/>
    </element>
    <element count="2">
        <element count="4">
            <element count="6"/>
            <element count="6"/>
        </element>
        <element count="4"/>
    </element> 
    <element count="2"/> 
 </body>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884129. @MichaelKay solves a very similar problem there. You can actually skip some of the steps since the level of indentation is already explicitly given in your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible XSLT 1.0 solution.  The trick here is to use a *key* to link each `element` to its nearest preceding sibling that has a strictly smaller `count` value.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="childrenByParent" match="element"
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::element[@count &lt; current()/@count][1])" />

  <xsl:template match="/body">
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('childrenByParent', '')" />
    </body>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element">
    <element>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('childrenByParent', generate-id())" />
    </element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The starting point `key('childrenByParent', '')` works because we need to start from the elements that *don't have* a "parent", i.e. those for which `preceding-sibling::element[@count &lt; current()/@count][1]` selects an empty node set, and the `generate-id` of an empty node set [is defined to be the empty string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-generate-id).

You ask in a comment what would need to change if the elements could be named anything as long as they have a `count` attribute.  In that case you'd just need to make a small change to the key definition to make it (a) match any element with a `count` and (b) look for the parent with *any* name rather than just `element`:

```
  <xsl:key name="childrenByParent" match="*[@count]"
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[@count &lt; current()/@count][1])" />
```

and to the second template to give it a more general `match` pattern, and to use `xsl:copy` instead of hard-coding the element name to create:

```
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('childrenByParent', generate-id())" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hmm, I developed this stylesheet using Xalan 2.7 and it works there, as well as on Saxon 9, but I've just tested it out using `xsltproc` for good measure and there it _doesn't_ work.  It appears that different processors have different opinions on whether `current()` is legal within the `use` expression of a key, so YMMV.

Comment: What would it happen if the elements are not called elements, but they can be anything, only that they need to have the count attribute?

Comment: @DavidMendezGonzalez it's just a couple of small changes, I've edited my answer with the details.

Comment: It works, but it does not copy the text within the element, and for some reason it adds the namespace on the first level as an attribute.

Comment: @DavidMendezGonzalez none of the elements in the question _had_ any text to copy... If you need this you'd have to add "`| text()`" to either the copy-of or the apply-templates. And likewise there were no namespaces in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `count` attributes have values `2,4,6,..` respectively you know the initial count and the difference between counts then it is easy:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(element)*">
  <xsl:param name="elements" as="element(element)*"/>
  <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:param name="step" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-starting-with="element[@count = $level]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., $level + $step, $step)"/>
    </xsl:copy>  
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="body">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(element, 2, 2)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```